# Only display savebox if own command is given

Tags: boxes

I'm experiencing a quite complicated and hard-to-explain problem:

I'm using own commands that create and fill saveboxes if they are called in the main `tex` file. Like this:

```
\newcommand{\Hello}[1]{\newsavebox{\HelloBox}\sbox{\Hellobox}{#1}}
```

Later on in the document, these boxes are being called and displayed:

```
\usebox{\Hellobox}
```

This works fine. What I'm achieving with this is that commands are given in the main document and I can align and layout them the way I want, no matter when which command is given.

**My problem:** This has to be conditional, i.e.: if the command `\Hello` is not called in the main document, `\usebox{\Hellobox}` must not be called either, because obviously it won't work because the box is not created. *Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use* `if` *constructions.*

What I'm trying to achieve as pseudo code:

```
if \Hello is being called in the main document
    create a savebox and fill it with content
if \Hello is not being called in the main document
    maybe create the savebox, but don't call it
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's usually a bad idea to allocate a register within another macro as if you re-run the command you will allocate a new register everytime. e-tex has more registers than classic TeX (which only had 256, half of which are typically used before your start)

```
\newsavebox{\HelloBox}
\newcommand{\Hello}[1]{\sbox{\Hellobox}{#1}}
```

Then you can use

```
\usebox{\Hellobox}
```

which will act like `\mbox{}` if it hasn't been set, or if you don't want even that you can use

```
\ifvoid\Hellobox\else\usebox{\Hellobox}\fi
```